# How to change the color of an active h5 tab using jQuery or CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I am trying to implement some code written by [Zoe Rooney](http://zoerooney.com/blog/tutorials/clean-tabbed-product-descriptions-for-shopify/). I was able to get everything working just fine, only issue I run into is formatting the tabs.

Here's what I have done, I have a file called tabs.js with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

// This first section is all about formatting the content correctly for tabs

// Add the opening list tag before the first H5 within the description 
$('.product-description h5:first-of-type').before('<ul class="tabs" />');

// Loop through each H5 in the description
$('.product-description h5').each(function(index, value){
    // Assign them each a number, in order
    var num = index + 1;

    // For each H5, wrap everything from after the heading to just before the next one in a div
    // Give each div a unique ID that includes those assigned numbers
    $(this).nextUntil('h5').wrapAll('<div class="tab-content" id="tab' + num + '" />');

    // For each h5, wrap the H5 itself in a list item and an anchor link to the div
    $(this).wrap('<li class="single-tab"><a href="#tab' + num + '"></a></li>');
});

// Wrap the whole list and the tab content divs in a surrounding div
$('ul.tabs, .tab-content').wrapAll('<div class="tab-area" />');

// Move that surrounding div after the form
$('.tab-area').appendTo('.content');

// Loop through the list items (the tab headers)
$('.single-tab').each(function(){
    // Move them into the list element
    $(this).appendTo('ul.tabs');
});


// The rest of this is the actual tab functionality, from http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/jquery-tabs/

$('ul.tabs').each(function(){

  // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
  // which tab is active and it's associated content
  var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

  // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
  // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
  $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
  $active.addClass('active');
  $content = $($active.attr('href'));

  // Hide the remaining content
  $links.not($active).each(function () {
    $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
  });

  // Bind the click event handler
  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
    // Make the old tab inactive.
    $active.removeClass('active');
    $content.hide();

    // Update the variables with the new link and content
    $active = $(this);
    $content = $($(this).attr('href'));

    // Make the tab active.
    $active.addClass('active');
    $content.show();

    // Prevent the anchor's default click action
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
});
```

And here is what I have for CSS:

```
.single-tab h5:hover {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    color:#666;
} 

.single-tab h5 {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
    color:#949494;
}

.single-tab li {
    list-style:none;
    display:inline;
}

.single-tab a {
    padding:0px 5px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ffffff;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.single-tab a.active {
    background:#787878;
    color:#0E67FF;
}

.single-tab{ 
    display: inline-block;  
    margin-right: 3% ;
    text-align: Left;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

The html for this section looks like this: ( note that this is pulled from the webpage using inspect element as the HTML is written using shopifys .liquid template.

```
<div class="product-description rte" itemprop="description">
  <p>Main Description</p>
  <p><strong>My titles here</strong><br> then some more description 
    <div class="tab-area">
        <ul class="tabs">
           <li class="single-tab">
             <a    href="#tab1" class="active" data-activator="#tab1">
               <h5><strong>First Tab</strong></h5>
             </a>
           </li>
           <li class="single-tab">
             <a href="#tab2" data-activator="#tab2" class="">
               <h5><strong>Second Tab</strong></h5>
             </a>
           </li>
        </ul>
     <div class="tab-content" id="tab1" style="display: block;">
        <p>Some mor info here</p></div><div class="tab-content" id="tab2"     style="display: none;">
        <ul>
            <li>some line content here</li>
        </ul>
```

As you can probably tell, I am very new to this, I am assuming I don't need all the classes I have set up as some overwrite others, but that's besides the point. What I am looking for is a way to change the text color of the active tab. I also don't want the active tab to highlight to a different color if its already selected. Can this even be done in CSS or do I need jQuery to get this done? Any ideas at all are appreciated.

Comment: Can you share you `html` structure?

Comment: Edited to share the html. TSorry bout that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I can gather from the example (I looked at the result from the link you provided) the class that is giving the h5 its properties is .tabs li a.active h5

However, that is not present in your CSS example. Your selector .single-tab a.active could be written again or rewritten as .single-tab a.active h5. That would select the h5 of the anchor tab that is currently active.

You would then change the color and/or background of that h5 with the color and/or background-color properties.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, figures it would be something so simple after all my playing around.